data warehouse and SCD
probably odd question but I never encountered a date 31.12.9999 in slowly changing dimension or tables with records and column like EndDate which should mean as the record is currently valid or there is no EndDate for order etc.
I have seen always 1.1.9999 for such scenarios.
the good reason would be for examole if you want to the date comparision to find gaps between orders. Let's say we have two order with start on 1.1.2024 and end 31.3.2024 and another order 1.4.2024 till 30.6.2024.  if you want to know if there is a gap or the orders are continuos the EndDate +1 >= StartDate could be used. If you have somewhere 31.12.9999 meaning the order's validity is infinit then adding 1 this date will throw an error as invalid date.
Do you have another use cases that 31.12.9999 is not a good date to be stored?

If you think using a specific end date will cause a problem with your query requirements then don’t use it and use a date that doesn’t cause an issue. I’m not really sure what the point of your question is - but I may be missing something?

@NickW. what is the best practice when using SCD and dates that define what records are active. For example usually I saw that actuve record has always 1.1.9999 when using SCD of type 2.

The best practice is to use any date far enough in the future that it will never be a “real” end date and which doesn’t cause problems with any calculations you might want to perform using this date
